# Impulse response aquired by ifft seems to require circshift

Tags: fourier-transform, finite-impulse-response, impulse-response, ifft, system-identification

On the system below:

[image]

I have found W by inputing 20-1000 frequency and found amplitude and phase for each frequency. I've tested for minimum phase and none min S. But the answer is not logical for me. I'm not sure algorithm works bad or what is behind this?

### Question:

W:

[image: W]

For the sake of ifft to extract impulse response:

```
W_=[0  zeros(1,19) (W)  zeros(1,6000) conj(flip((W))) zeros(1,19)];
w=real(ifft(W_));
```

w:

[image: w]

But lets take a look at `freqz(circshift(w,4000))`: (Note: `w`'s length is 8000)

[image: freqz(circshift(w,4000))]

The phase is unbelievable. This phase response happens if S being minphase. Also the stablized w by removing peaks from W has still this behaviour in it's phase, why? Why linear phase, my systems does not have such high degree of phase linearity!

It seems maybe we can have aliazing after `ifft`, am I right? how?